# Change Ctrl+Arrow and Ctrl+Shift+Arrow to jump/jump+select a single word rather than the whole line?

Tags: macos, keyboard, settings, shortcut-menu

In order to change the way <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd> function on OS X so it matches other devices I frequently utilised [this 'hack'](http://mwholt.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/fix-home-and-end-keys-on-mac-os-x.html?m=1). Is there a similar way to override the way <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> work?

I appreciate that if I was completely moving to OS X it's silly, however, when all other devices use these keys in this fashion it makes sense to reconfigure them on the one device that doesn't match.

In short, I want to make <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left/right arrow</kbd> jump by word/punctuation separator as it does on Ubuntu and Windows rather than to the end of line.

I would prefer to use a native override rather than installing an app to perform this task, but if that's not possible then please let me know of any apps.

Comment: I assume know that opt+arrow does this?

Comment: Yeah I do know that - thanks.
Though like I said above, I want to have the same functionality as other operating systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
  "^\UF702" = moveWordLeft:;
  "^\UF703" = moveWordRight:;
  "^$\UF702" = moveWordLeftAndModifySelection:;
  "^$\UF703" = moveWordRightAndModifySelection:;
}
```

Then quit and reopen applications to apply the changes.

See http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html or http://lri.me/keybindings.html for more information.